# Is there a difference between using a single vs. double brace (delimiters) in SugarCRM Smarty tpls command construct?

Tags: smarty, sugarcrm

I noticed in a template I'm editing that sometimes there is a construct like:

```
{if} ... {/if}
```

and other times:

```
{{if}} ... {{/if}}
```

I'm just wondering what the functional difference is (if any) between these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SugarCRM use "{{" and “}}” double brackets around sugar UI variables. This section would be evaluated when sugar are creating cache file. Sugar does not use the tpl files, they preprocess it and generate a cached Smarty tpl, then use smarty to handle the generated cached templates. The double brackets to distinguish between the stage for generating the template file and the stage for processing the runtime view.

This is implemented in EditView, more information can be found here: http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.1_html.html#9003870

Comment: Oh, interesting.  So {{}} get cached and {} do not, great to know :)

Answer (score 1):

This is only true for EditViews and DetailViews, where we use two pass rendering for building these forms from metadata. All other forums don't need this.

Comment: I was working on the Contacts Detail View, so that makes sense.  Thanks.