# Iterating an array via Smarty in SugarCRM

Tags: smarty, sugarcrm

When iterating an array in Smarty I am getting results conflicting with a `print_r()` of the same array.

When doing a `print_r()` on the array I can see that there are 2 objects in the array and each object is unique. However, when I run a `print_r()` on each item of the array (via `foreach` loop) I seem to get the same results for each item.

Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

See the below code examples and results.

Code:

```
{$fields.rgggo_spreadsheetcellmap_documents.value->beans|@print_r}
```

Ouput:

```
Array
(
    [a852b076-a5cb-dda9-3868-52010d6957ab] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap Object
        (
            [new_schema] => 1
            [module_dir] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap
            [object_name] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap
            [table_name] => rgggo_spreadsheetcellmap
            [importable] => 
            [id] => a852b076-a5cb-dda9-3868-52010d6957ab
            [name] => 
            [date_entered] => 08/06/2013 09:52am
            [date_modified] => 08/06/2013 02:16pm
            [modified_user_id] => 1
            [modified_by_name] => Sean
            [created_by] => 1
            [created_by_name] => Sean
            [description] => Test 2
            [deleted] => 0
            [created_by_link] => 
            [modified_user_link] => 
            [team_id] => 2e201ae4-fac9-8426-44c5-4f54f5830831
            [team_set_id] => 65bd59b2-b3ed-fb2b-6a85-4f8888229942
            [team_count] => 
            [team_name] => Development
            [team_link] => 
            [team_count_link] => 
            [teams] => 
            [assigned_user_id] => 
            [assigned_user_name] => 
            [assigned_user_link] => 
            [field] => document_type_text_c
            [row] => 3
            [col] => 1

            .... a bunch more stuff here
        )

    [f038918d-a13d-69f0-3541-51fff82f0497] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap Object
        (
            [new_schema] => 1
            [module_dir] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap
            [object_name] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap
            [table_name] => rgggo_spreadsheetcellmap
            [importable] => 
            [id] => f038918d-a13d-69f0-3541-51fff82f0497
            [name] => 
            [date_entered] => 08/05/2013 02:10pm
            [date_modified] => 08/06/2013 02:17pm
            [modified_user_id] => 1
            [modified_by_name] => Sean
            [created_by] => 1
            [created_by_name] => Sean
            [description] => 
            [deleted] => 0
            [created_by_link] => 
            [modified_user_link] => 
            [team_id] => 2e201ae4-fac9-8426-44c5-4f54f5830831
            [team_set_id] => 65bd59b2-b3ed-fb2b-6a85-4f8888229942
            [team_count] => 
            [team_name] => Development
            [team_link] => 
            [team_count_link] => 
            [teams] => 
            [assigned_user_id] => 
            [assigned_user_name] => 
            [assigned_user_link] => 
            [field] => description
            [row] => 2
            [col] => 1

            .... a bunch more stuff here
        )
)
```

When I iterate the array...

```
{{foreach from=$fields.rgggo_spreadsheetcellmap_documents.value->beans key=k item=v}}
    <pre>
    {$v|@print_r}
    </pre>
{{/foreach}}
```

I get these results:

```
RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap Object
(
    [new_schema] => 1
    [module_dir] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap
    [object_name] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap
    [table_name] => rgggo_spreadsheetcellmap
    [importable] => 
    [id] => f038918d-a13d-69f0-3541-51fff82f0497
    [name] => 
    [date_entered] => 08/05/2013 02:10pm
    [date_modified] => 08/06/2013 02:17pm
    [modified_user_id] => 1
    [modified_by_name] => Sean
    [created_by] => 1
    [created_by_name] => Sean
    [description] => 
    [deleted] => 0
    [created_by_link] => 
    [modified_user_link] => 
    [team_id] => 2e201ae4-fac9-8426-44c5-4f54f5830831
    [team_set_id] => 65bd59b2-b3ed-fb2b-6a85-4f8888229942
    [team_count] => 
    [team_name] => Development
    [team_link] => 
    [team_count_link] => 
    [teams] => 
    [assigned_user_id] => 
    [assigned_user_name] => 
    [assigned_user_link] => 
    [field] => description
    [row] => 2
    [col] => 1

    .... a bunch more stuff here
)

    RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap Object
(
    [new_schema] => 1
    [module_dir] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap
    [object_name] => RGGGO_SpreadsheetCellMap
    [table_name] => rgggo_spreadsheetcellmap
    [importable] => 
    [id] => f038918d-a13d-69f0-3541-51fff82f0497
    [name] => 
    [date_entered] => 08/05/2013 02:10pm
    [date_modified] => 08/06/2013 02:17pm
    [modified_user_id] => 1
    [modified_by_name] => Sean
    [created_by] => 1
    [created_by_name] => Sean
    [description] => 
    [deleted] => 0
    [created_by_link] => 
    [modified_user_link] => 
    [team_id] => 2e201ae4-fac9-8426-44c5-4f54f5830831
    [team_set_id] => 65bd59b2-b3ed-fb2b-6a85-4f8888229942
    [team_count] => 
    [team_name] => Development
    [team_link] => 
    [team_count_link] => 
    [teams] => 
    [assigned_user_id] => 
    [assigned_user_name] => 
    [assigned_user_link] => 
    [field] => description
    [row] => 2
    [col] => 1

    .... a bunch more stuff here
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another stackoverflow question. The issue is double vs single curly brackets and their use in SugarCRM.

[Is there a difference between using a single vs. double brace (delimiters) in SugarCRM Smarty tpls command construct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455123/is-there-a-difference-between-using-a-single-vs-double-brace-delimiters-in-su)